# How to i18n notifications generated on server and read by distinct clients?

Tags: internationalization

The server side detect events and store the information to notify the user. When the user opens one of the multiple clients (web, Android, iOS) it sees a indication that there are new notifications. The user can read the notification message.

The clients support multiple languages.

We got stuck searching for a good solution to solve the internationalization of the notifications. Our current possible solutions are:

- Generate already translated notification on server based on user information (last accessed language or profile preference).
- Generate notifications with an identifier and parameters and i18n on clients.

There are any best practices on this? 
Is there any proven solution on this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any general "best practices" other than your OS's developers guide (such as [this one for Android](https://developer.android.com/intl/en/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)), but they probably don't apply to your use case.

My advice would be to mix your two approaches: always send an identifier with your message so it can be translated on the platform if possible, but also send a fallback message generated on your server (from info you have on the client or even default to english) in cases where you had to add a new notification type and the client is not yet updated with the latest translation file version.